# Showing all customers for each date record provided after they were onboarded

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, left-join

`Date_spine` Table: It has all the dates of the month of march, 2020

```
DATE  
2020-03-01  
2020-03-02  
2020-03-03  
2020-03-04  
2020-03-05  
2020-03-06  
2020-03-07
```

`Customer` table:

```
id  |  customer_name | onboarding_date     
123 | Ainc           | 2020-03-02  
124 | Binc           | 2020-03-03
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**: For every date in the `date_spine` table we need to *show all the customers* on or after they onboarded. However, we don't need to see the date where there were no customers. For example: `2020-03-01` doesn't show up in the desired output because by that day no customer had on-boarded.

```
DATE         | CUSTOMER  
2020-03-02   | Ainc  
2020-03-03   | Ainc   
2020-03-03   | Binc  
2020-03-04   | Ainc  
2020-03-04   | Binc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` on an inequality condition:

```
select d.date, c.customer_name
from customer c
inner join date_spine d on d.date >= c.onboarding_date
order by d.date, c.customer_name
```

Comment: Thank you so much GMB, it works. Appreciate your time.